# Unit test faces NullReferenceException when try to access a private accessor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection, access-levels

In the main application:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Patient
    {
    ...
        public double height { get; private set; }
```

And in unit test:

```
Patient p1=new Patient();
BindingFlags flags=BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
typeof(Patient).GetField("height", flags).SetValue(p1, "67.2");
```

My unit test does not work and it gives me

> UnitTest.MyTest.idealCal threw exception: 
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

The error occures at the line of `SetValue`

How to fix it?

Comment: Why do you use `NonPublic` when it's public? Why do you even use reflection at all instead of just, you know, `p1.height`?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel but its set accessor is private.Even `BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Public` gives the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to retrieve a *Field* but you're actually using a *Property*.

Consider this situation:

```
public class X
{
    public double Height { get; private set; }
}
```

You can now set a value using this code:

```
void Main()
{
    var obj = new X();
    var property = typeof(X).GetProperty("Height", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    var setMethod = property.GetSetMethod(true);
    setMethod.Invoke(obj, new object[]{ 5.0 });
    Console.WriteLine (obj.Height);
}
```

The working is simple: get the property (notice naming conventions) which is public, get its private set method (that's what the `true` argument is for) and invoke that setter with the value you wish to set it as.

Do note that accessing private members as part of a unit test is typically an indication you're doing something wrong. This is a too big topic to elaborate on here though.